# Selected option Id and value

Tags: knockout.js

Normally when I have a select list I bind it with knockout like this:

```
<select
    data-bind="
        options: data,
        optionsText: 'Name',
        optionsValue: 'Id',
        optionsCaption: 'Select ...',
        value: dataSelectedId" ></select>
```

But there's a problem with such binding: you do not have the selected object. You have its ID instead. **How to merge this two requirements: have binding to both item's id and item itself?**

Right now I use `computed` observable to get selected item, which usually looks like this:

```
self.dataSelectedCO = ko.computed(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.data().length; ++i)
        if (self.data()[i].Id() == self.dataSelectedId())
            return self.data()[i];
});
```

I've tried to wrap value getter using a custom function but it's called for every element when selection changes, so there are no benefits here of using this approach. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkpsj/8/)'s a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `optionsValue` parameter. Then the selected value will be the 'selected item' instead of the `Id`.

The updated code will be:

```
<select
    data-bind="
    options: data,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    optionsCaption: 'Select ...',
    value: dataSelectedItem" ></select>
```

`dataSelectedItem` will now have the selected item.

Once you have the item. you can get the `Id` from the object itself like `dataSelectedItem().Id`

Comment: I can't do it this way, because then I cannot place this SELECT in a form which is send to server unless I make additional hidden field for selected ID. But using hidden field with ID bound to it would make it.

Comment: If you want the Id as the value of SELECT, then using computed observable for selected item is a very good approach.